# dual Client Samba Mount Icons

Tags: samba, icons, fstab

I am auto mounting multiple samba network drives on a Ubuntu client through using the following line in `fstab` as an example:

```
//LINUX-SERVER/bee_dsk5/ /media/bee_dsk5/ cifs defaults,nodev,noexec,nouser,rw,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,credentials=/root/.smbfscredentials 0 0
```

The network drives are provided by my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

This works fine but creates both a Device and Network icon which I have on my desktop. If I umount these drives and them mount only the Network Icon exists. Also if I logout (not reboot) and log back in only the Network Icon exists. It does not matter if I use nautilus or nemo (my prefered). Any ideas on how to modify so have only the 1 Icon on startup.

This issues has existed through multiple versions of Ubuntu at least 14 and 16. The client is currently on 17.10.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I should have also stated I use Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the duplicate icons by using `dconf-editor`.

Scroll down to com → canonical → unity → devices and enter the UUID of the mount in blacklist.

Mine looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I use gnome and not unity. I can find no equivalent item under the Gnome, Nemo, Cinnamon areas in dconf-editor. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Sorry! I am unfamiliar with gnome.